# Can't add object to NSMutableDictionary within Parse block

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, nsmutabledictionary

I am downloading a sticker object from Parse.com and then downloading the image for it. For some reason it won't add to my dictionary. The object is created fine but it just won't add. code below:

```
- (void)getNewStickersWithCompletionHandler:(stickerCompletionHandler)handler
{


    __weak StickerManager *weakSelf = self;
    PFQuery *stickersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"sticker"];
    NSNumber *total =[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[self.stickerDictionary count]];
    //im not sure this is a great way to add what if we miss one..there will be an error
    [stickersQuery whereKey:@"stickerNO" greaterThan:total];
    [stickersQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if(!error) {



            for( PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSString *title = object[@"title"];
                int stickerNO = [[object objectForKey:@"stickerNO"] intValue];


                //DOWNLOAD IMAGE CODE
                PFFile *image = object[@"image"];
                [image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                    if(!error){

                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        Sticker *sticker = [[Sticker alloc] initWithTitle:title stickerNO:stickerNO image:image];
                        NSLog(@"%@",sticker.title);
                        //sticker has been created! but won’t add!
                        [weakSelf.stickerDictionary setObject:sticker forKey:sticker.title];
                    }

                }];//end get image block




            }//end for



            handler(YES,nil);


        }
    }];//end download stickers block


}
```

Not sure what's going on here, it's driving me a  bit mad. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: One thing I will check is if 'stickerDictionary' is instantiated(lazy instantiation or in some other init). Cause in objective-c calling methods on nil can be hard to detect. Can you paste your Dictionary instantiation code?

Comment: Are you sure weakSelf != nil? If it is not, are you sure stickerDictionary != nil?

Comment: The dictionary is initialised yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue is because of this line:

```
handler(YES,nil);
```

this is running at the end of your outer block, however the images are being downloaded by inner blocks in a for loop. The for loop is going to fire off all of these inner blocks, then finish and run your completion handler, then some time later your images will arrive.

You need to wait until all of these inner blocks have finished.

**Note**

Simply moving the completion call into the inner block will not work if there are more than 1 images to download, so you will need to track the list and have the inner block fire when the last image is downloaded. Keeping in mind they could arrive at different times, so its not simply fire on the last inner block, but rather fire when they have all returned either a success or error. So increase a counter in every inner block, then in the inner block check if the count has reached the number of images you were expecting

Comment: whoah! yes that fixed it. I moved it into the inner block. The problem now though is that I only want to call handler(YES,nil) once when all the images are downloaded...won't this call it multiple times if I have 2 images downloading?

Comment: @Kex yes it will, so you will need to track the list and have the inner block fire when the last image is downloaded. Keeping in mind they could arrive at different times, so its not simply fire on the last inner block, but rather fire when they have all returned either a success or error. So increase a counter in every inner block, then in the inner block check if the count has reached the number of images you were expecting

Comment: @Kex no prob dude, have fun